# How to convert contrast ratio to number of stops?

Tags: luminosity

I have read an article from the below link about the human eye sensitivity and came to know that its dynamic contrast range is 1000000:1 or in other words 30 stops. They also mentioned static contrast ratio of 1000:1 is same as 10 stops. I believe if we have a million lights with light intensity from 1 to million, our human eye may able to see only 30 shades in that. I want to know how to relate the intensity to stops. Please give more clarification if i seems to be sounding like dumbo. Thanks.

https://wolfcrow.com/notes-by-dr-optoglass-dynamic-range-of-the-human-eye/

Comment: Did you intend to include the link? It's not anywhere right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "stops" you are mentioning are the ones from photography.  One stop there means "double", as aperture and exposure time are usually set at discrete interval 2x apart. Many sensors, like the eye and the ears, work exponentially, not linearly. See for example the Decibel for sound intensity. The eye, as you wrote, can distinguish a number of light shades proportional to the number of stops (the logarithm of the contrast), not the arithmetic contrast.

So one stop is a 2:1 ratio;

Two stops, $2^2 =4$, 4:1 ratio

10 stops is $2^{10} =1024 \simeq 1000$

30 stops is $2^{30} =1024^3 \simeq 1000\, 000 \, 000$

Comment: Thanks so much. yes exactly like decibels. The answer made my day!